# How to fix the while loop

Tags: python, aiogram

I am writing a telegram bot for ordering and paying for pizza, the menu is in the database. I need to write a while loop so that it reads the response from the database and outputs each position from the menu with a separate message at the /menu command. Now it works, but if the user restarts the bot, he will simply send a message "choose a pizza" without a menu. I'm new to python and now I'm being stupid and I can't come up with a solution to this problem on my own, please help.

```
i = 0
    while i < len(request):
        name = request[i][0]
        description = request[i][1]
        price = request[i][2]
        photo = request[i][3]
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"{name}\n\n" + f"{description}" + '[.]' + '(' + f"{photo}" + ')'
              + "\n\nPRICE: " + price + " $",
                           parse_mode='markdown')
        i += 1
    return await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Choose pizza!',
                                  reply_markup=markups.menu)
```

Comment: Looks like you can do `for name, description, price, photo in request:` and then directly use the variables? Normally, `for` loops are preferable over `while`. (If there are more elements than the ones you specified, try `for name, description, price, photo, *_ in request:`.)

Comment: @fsimonjetz unfortunately, this does not solve the problem, since the variable i acts as a counter for entries in the database, and when the cycle passes through the dictionary once, the second time does not occur, because the counter is not updated.

Comment: `request = cursor.fetchall()
for name, description, price, photo in request:` This code also works once